# Can a quantum mechanical system have more than one wave-function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, linear-algebra, superposition

I was told that a quantum mechanical system is completely determined by its wave function. But superposition principle says that given two wave functions of some system, a linear combination of them is also a wave function for the same system.

I'm confused, how can it be that the same system have more than one wave function. ***How to clarify this confusion?***

I think that this means that every wave-function corresponds to a particular state of the system, but I don't understand what does that mean? What is the exact meaning of a state of a system in this context? Can you give some examples of states of a system?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145050/discussion-on-question-by-fawzy-hegab-can-a-quantum-mechanical-system-have-more); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: trivially, and probably not what you asking about, the wave functions $\psi (x)$ and $ e^{i \phi} \psi (x)$  have the same probability density.

Answer (score 0):

One example for a quantum mechanical system is "one free electron in 3-dimensional space". The state "the electron is at the point $\vec x_1$" is described by one wave function $\psi_1(\vec x)$, the state "the electron is at the point $\vec x_2$" is described by another wave function $\psi_2(\vec x)$, and a third wave function $\psi_3(\vec x) \sim \psi_1(\vec x) + \psi_2(\vec x)$ describes the superposition of those two states.

Answer (score 0):

Just considers a one dimensional system, where the Hamiltonian is given by $$H = \frac{-\hbar^2 \partial_x^2}{2m}.$$ You want to solve the time-independent Schrödinger equation $$H \Psi = E \Psi.\tag{1}\label{eq:1}$$ The solution are simply given by plane-wave, i.e. $e^{\pm ikx}$ where $k = \sqrt{2mE}$. So you see that there is two wave function solutions to ($\ref{eq:1}$). But because ($\ref{eq:1}$) is a linear equation the superposition of the two will be also be a solution. So you can write the general solution

$$\Psi = A e^{ ikx} + B e^{ -ikx},$$ where $A$, $B$ will be given by some boundary condition.